# Deploying ASP.NET Core with EF migrations to Azure

Tags: asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

When trying to publish a asp.net core 1.0.1 project using EF to Azure, I get an error:

```
System.InvalidOperationException: The migration 'BjÃ¶rk\AppData\Local\Temp\PublishTemp\obj\....ApplicationDbContext.sql' was not found.
```

It works fine if I uncheck the "Apply this migration on publish", but of course the database will not be updated accordingly if I don't check that box.

This should probably be a bug report and not a stackoverflow question... :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is probably in the path, the swedish letter "ö" caused an issue.

**Workaround:**

Uncheck the "Apply this migration on publish" so that you are able to publish everything except migrations from your normal account.
Make a new account/profile on your PC without any non-english letters. Login to that account and publish your project every time you have a pending migration.

Answer (score 0):

I reached out to someone on the team, and it looks like this is a known issue that will be fixed in VS "15". Until then, you can download [the latest version of publish-module.psm1](https://github.com/aspnet/vsweb-publish/blob/master/publish-module.psm1) which includes the fix.

Comment: Thanks for your input. This does not seem to work for me though, so I still have to use the workaround above.